# Codeigniter does not allow fetch of media in iframe

Tags: php, codeigniter, iframe, modal-dialog

I have a files that stored in `storage/employeeImages` also the file name stored in database. When I want fetch files and show in modal using iFrame I'm facing 403 error.

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#<?= $employee['emp_id'];?>">
     <img src="<?= base_url("/storage/employeeImages/".$employee['image']);?>" width="400" height="400">
</a>



<div class="modal fade" id="<?= $employee['emp_id'];?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                         <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"><?= $employee['name'];?></h4>
                       </div>
                      <div class="modal-body">
                      <iframe src="<?= base_url("/storage/employeeImages/".$employee['image']);?>>" style="width:100%;height:100%"></iframe>  
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-footer">
                      <a href="<?= base_url("/storage/employeeImages/".$employee['image']);?>" class="btn btn-default bg-blue" download>download<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span></a>  
                      </div>
                   </div>
                 </div>
               </div>
```

Comment: What do you see when you view the generated HTML? In your browser - do a View Source or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Error 403 simply means you are trying to access a forbidden access file. You might want to check your folder properties or try moving it to an accessible directory(maybe a public folder).